# IE issue disabling open in download dialog

Tags: internet-explorer, download, telerik, telerik-grid

I want that use should not have able "OPEN" file directly from the IE download dialog. 
I tried
.
It works well too. but  it doesn't work if user try download (export to excel) from a popup window or modal-dialog window.

why this is not working? is there any other way to do it?

Comment: I am using 
<meta  http-equiv="Refresh" name="DownloadOptions" content="noopen" /> but it is not working if download button or link is in popup

Answer (score 0):

Your IE 8 or 9, try again after update IE